# Java CEF - Is it possible to access DOM document and elements of loaded page?

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I've built java-cef from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/overview , but I still can't find any info in docs and javadocs about how to access DOM document and elements of loaded page.

I need to access elements by something like `document.getElementsByClassName("example");`, `document.getElementsByTagName("div");`.

Something like in JSoup - https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax :

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");
```

Is there same functional in Java-CEF?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to attach a load handler to the CEF Client and call `CefBrowser::executeJavaScript(String code)` inside the handler, e.g.:

```
cefClient.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler());
...
class LoadHandler extends CefLoadHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onLoadEnd(CefBrowser browser, int frameId, int status) {
        String jscode = "var x = document.getElementsByClassName('example')";
        browser.executeJavaScript(jscode);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Then if you want to receive events from the browser script in  your Java code, you need to register a call `cefQuery` with `CefBrowser::executeJavaScript(String code)`, passing all necessary data in a single argument, and receive it with a message router, e.g:

```
CefMessageRouter msgRouter = CefMessageRouter.create();
msgRouter.addHandler(new MessageRouterHandler(), true);
cefClient.addMessageRouter(msgRouter);
...
browser.executeJavaScript("cefQuery({request: 'Hello World'})");
...
class MessageRouterHandler extends CefMessageRouterHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean onQuery(CefBrowser browser, long query_id, String request, boolean persistent, CefQueryCallback callback) {
        System.out.println(request); // prints "Hello World"
        
        return true;
    }
}
```